# LightBox won't open - Probably some JavaScript mistake

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, lightbox

I've been trying to implement [LightBox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2). I've been trying to follow the "official" guide and searching on the net - without any luck at all.

The problem is as follows: When I click the image, it just opens as it was a normal link. It doesn't register I've clicked on it. I also tried to follow [this](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#support):

If the solution need some kind of tracking in the jQuery code, please add a small note on how to do the tracking :)

Currently I have the following rendered code (using ASP.NET):

The image itself:

```
<a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_MainImageLink" rel="lightbox" href="../../../Media/ProductImages/KaninbamseKnirke1.jpg">    
    <img id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_MainImage" title="Kanin bamse Knirke" class="ProductImage" src="../../../Media/ProductImages/KaninbamseKnirke1.jpg" alt="Kanin bamse Knirke" style="height:280px;width:280px;" />    
</a>
```

My head tag (and yes - the paths work):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../Styles/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script src="../../../js/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../../../js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../../../js/lightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="../../../Styles/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My body tag:

As I have the problem described above, I've tryed both with this active and not. The initLightBox is the method I've set to fire onload, as described on the Lightbox homepage.

```
<body id="Masterbackground" onload="initLightbox();" class="badeandnav">
```

For what is it worth - my doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have conflict, the jQuery with the Prototype. Ether remove jQuery if you not use it, ether set compatibility mode for one of the two.
Eg, for `jQuery` you can set the `noConflict()` and then call it using the `jQuery` parametre.

```
<script src="prototype.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
 jQuery.noConflict();

 // Use jQuery via jQuery(...)
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery("div").hide();
 });

 // Use Prototype with $(...), etc.
 $('someid').hide();
</script>
```

Using jQuery with Other Libraries :
http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Answer (score 1):

from what i can tell in [this help page](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#how), your lightbox shouldn't work with jQuery, but should work with [Prototype.js](http://www.prototypejs.org/) and [Scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/)

If you are going to use Jquery and prototype at the same time, one of them will have to run in no-conflict mode, or neither will work properly.
You can do this, by loading jQuery first, then running

`jQuery.noConflict()`

([read the skinny on noConflict here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/))

and then loading prototype and scriptaculous.

You can then still call jQuery, but no longer by using `$()`, (`$()` will invoke prototype.js), but by using `jQuery();`